# zipimport.ZipImportError: can't decompress data; zlib not available

Tags: python, python-3.x, py2exe, cx-freeze

I would like to use **cx_freeze** to change my **hello_world.py** into **exe** file.

When I run cxfreeze like this:

```
cxfreeze hello_world.py
```

And I run the exe file, it comes the error:

```
./hello_world 
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/karl/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/encodings/__init__.py", line 31, in <module>
zipimport.ZipImportError: can't decompress data; zlib not available
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: I had a similar issue, maybe this can help you, but it didnt make it for me... https://github.com/peacegiverman/cx_Freeze-deb-wheels

Answer (score 11):

Run the below code which will install zlib:

```
sudo installer -pkg /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg -target /
```

Thanks to the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/52756409/9162193

Comment: Works on OSX Mojave! Thanks!

Comment: I get the following error `installer: Error - the package path specified was invalid: '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg'.` on Mojave 10.14

Answer (score 2):

On MacOS the issue is often that an XCode update has removed zlib. The solution in these cases would be running:

```
xcode-select --install
```

On Linux machines you would need to install zlib, see for instance [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43464623/2532070).

Comment: This no longer seems to ship zlib on OSX Mojave

Comment: this returns an error (I am on macOS Mojave, Version 10.14): xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates

Comment: This worked for me on macOS Mojave - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23749530/brew-install-zlib-devel-on-mac-os-x-mavericks#answer-52900711