# How can I install zlib on Mac OS X Mojave (10.14)?

Tags: homebrew, zlib, pyenv, macos-mojave, xcode-command-line-tools

I recently upgraded from Sierra to Mojave. After that I tried to use `pyenv install 3.5.6`. This uses homebrew in the background to try to install python, which fails with `zipimport.ZipImportError: can't decompress data; zlib not available`. The same command worked before the upgrade.

This question has been asked before and the generally accepted solution is to install xcode command line tools using this command: `xcode-select --install`.

I have both xcode 10 and the command line tools installed but zlib is still unavailable.

I tried installing zlib using homebrew but that didn't work either.

(Incidentally I also looked into installing python from a binary but there's no v3.5.6 binary for Mac OS X)

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/1219

```
sudo installer -pkg /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg -target /
```

Comment: Confirmed.. This works on Mojave 10.14. Also it doesn't require you to install XCode  or XCode command line tools separately.

Comment: This answer solves my `pyenv install 3.6.8` problem. Thanks!

Comment: There is nothing there for me, the only thing in here look to be: `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/share/man/whatis`.

Comment: On the other hand the cflag workaround in the link worked, ie. `CFLAGS="-I$(xcrun --show-sdk-path)/usr/include" pyenv install 3.6.8`

Comment: These headers aren't available in Catalina, best as I can tell...

Answer (score 3):

It helped me as well, answer is here: 
https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/29176
More details, this works:

1. `brew update`
2. (Re)Install CLT.

   ```
   installer -pkg /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg -target /
   ```
3. `brew reinstall python@2`

Answer (score 1):

I needed an extra step to get it running on Mojave 10.14.05, Python 3.7. First:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin"
```

then

```
sudo installer -pkg /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg -target /
```

see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46391721/pipenv-command-not-found#answer-49842670).